# Read permission denied for pdf files on external drive created from google chrome or saved from google chrome

Tags: 14.04, permissions, hard-drive, google-chrome, pdf

I am migrating from macos X to ubuntu 14.04. While doing so, I took back up of all the files on macbook on an external 1TB hard drive. Now, I am trying to copy pdf files from external hard drive to ubuntu machine. I am able to copy all the files except pdf files created using Google Chrome on mac and pdf files saved from Google Chrome. The error I am getting is as below. Could anyone help me fix this.

Unable to open document “file:///media/user/disk/test.pdf”.

Error opening file: Permission denied

Please note that this only happens when I have stored pdf from Google Chrome or saved a web page as pdf from Google Chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a little more info, If it is an issue with Google chrome PDF do you have Google chrome currently installed on Ubuntu? https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html ; Can you see them in the hard drive? Right click on file go to "properties, permissions"? [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)

Comment: @DnrDevil: yes. I have installed Google chrome properly. In fact, I am typing this comment in Google Chrome. Nevertheless, does it matter if Google chrome is installed or not? To me it looks like a problem of Ubuntu or Google Chrome. But I am not an Ubuntu pro. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.